# Error while overwriting a file in java windows

Tags: java, eclipse

```
File inputFile = new File("abc.txt");
File tempFile = new File("temp.txt");
try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) tempFile.length()];
    fis.read(data);
    fis.close();

    String source = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    try{
        while(!inputFile.renameTo(inputFile)) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Some error occured");
    }

    FileWriter newfile = new FileWriter(inputFile, false);
    newfile.write(source);
    newfile.close();
    if (!tempFile.delete()) {
        System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        return;
    } 
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Successful");
    }
}                       
catch(IOException e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this program, I am trying to copy all the `data` from `temp.txt` into a string variable `source`. Then overwrite the file `abc.txt` with that string.

At first it showed me an exception as:

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

and then I found a solution on internet to rename the file as shown in code. Now, it does not give me the error, but the program does not terminate at all. What is wrong with this program? Why does not it give any error? Please help me out. Thank you so much.

**PS:** I am using windows 10 and Eclipse Juno as IDE.

Comment: Why are you trying to rename the file to the same name it already has?

Comment: I'm not going to lie I tried your code exactly and nothing went wrong for me. what else is going on would be the real question? Also the above post has a good point there... lol

Comment: The exception you received probably means you have the file open in a text editor.  It was telling you exactly what was wrong, i.e. the file "is being used by another process".

Comment: @Robert I just saw a solution to that problem on stackoverflow itself, so i tried it and it didn't give me any error :)

Comment: @JimGarrison I didnt have that file opened. But now instead of eclipse i tried compiling through command prompt, it worked perfectly :) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

the program which you wrote worked for me and it successfully terminated.There is no need for renaming the file.

```
try
    {
     String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("temp.txt")));
     Files.write(Paths.get("abc.txt"), content.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```